# how can make fuzzy commitment to take np array instead of bytes

Tags: python, numpy, fuzzy, bitvector

I'm trying to use the fuzzy commitment in https://github.com/cburkert/fuzzy-commitment and i want to use witness as np array  in:

```
    c = cs.commit(witness,message)
```

where :
message: A binary message to commit to.
witness: A witness to the commitment.

I write a pace of code to convert np array to bitvector array to be xord later with message (same type)

the function is (as in line 14 https://github.com/cburkert/fuzzy-commitment/blob/master/fcs/fcs.py) but instead of bytes it was a list or numpy array:

```
    def list_extractor1(value: list) -> BitVector:
        b=np.array(np.zeros((len(value))))

        for i in range(len(value)):
            b[i]=bin(int(value[i]))[2:].zfill(8)

     return BitVector(bitlist=b)
```

but, may i have an error
my array is:

```
    a=[1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

then I create a FCS object with 5 bits and 1 error

```
   cs = FCS(5, 1, extractor=list_extractor1) #5 as 'a' length
   c = cs.commit(a, b"\x01")  # uses a random message to commit to
```

then i put same feature vector and i receive "false"  instead of "true"

```
    cs.verify(c, b"\x03")  # Verification succeeds. One bit changed.
    >> False
```

could you please help me to find the error, the output should be true not false!
or

could you help me to make a list extractor doing wثll instead of 'list_extractor1'

thank you ...